# Bootstrap | How to include files or link?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

What is the best way to include bootstrap in html in files or link?

```
link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"
link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"
```

or

```
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

or both ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a CDN link (second option) for including libraries is generally considered a better approach since there are chances that many users would already have these files **cached** in their browsers resulting in faster page loads, you save bandwidth as these files are not hosted on your server and leverage lower response times from CDN servers.

I assume that you'll keep your custom styles(if any) in a separate file which anyways has to be stored on your server and loaded from there.

Whereas in the first option, the browser has to download the files when a user visits your site for the first time resulting in a slight overhead.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how popular the file that you want to include

**If it's more popular (by popular I mean most of the people on the web are using the same css and js files)** like in your case (bootstrap.min.css), use CDN URL.
The reason for that lots of sites might be using same CDN URL and probably get it from there, so you have a decent chance of that file already being cached when a user gets to your site.